# Imported OBJ file is missing parts of the model - malformed?

Tags: mesh, import

I want to import an OBJ model into Blender for rendering, but instead of the entire model, I only see three small submeshes of it:
[image: Screenshot of the Blender viewport]

The OBJ file itself is here: [case-on.obj.zip](https://bubbelsearch.de/files/case-on.obj.zip)

I used Apple's Model I/O framework to convert it from USDZ to OBJ. The original model is significantly more than just three small meshes. I've worked with the OBJ format before, but I can't find any obvious errors in the file itself. The USDZ model renders just fine in Preview.app, so I doubt it's faulty.

Apart from waiting for Apple to fix the converter, is there anything I can change in the file to make it work with Blender now?

Comment: I see the same in the Windows 3D Viewer so probably the file is wrong.

Comment: Yeah, that's sorta the premise of the question. The thing is that there's 24 MB of vertex data in the file, and that can't possibly just be the three meshes you see in the screenshot. Where did the rest go?